# python proxy script have some problems

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, proxy

i was tried to use asyncio and threading libraries in different scripts. but threading will cause this error in high connections:

```
filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

my source that cause this error:

```
try:
    reader, _, _ = select.select([socket_src, socket_dst], [], [], 1)
except select.error as err:
    error("Select failed", err)
```

i tried to increase fd limit but it not fix this error.

and in asyncio library:

1. after run script everything is ok.
2. after 20 minutes of running script, users will connect to proxy after about 1 min of send request
3. and any user can not connect to proxy after 1 hour...

my source:

```
import socket
import asyncio
import aiosocks
from struct import pack, unpack


class Client(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
    self.transport = transport
    self.server_transport = None

    def data_received(self, data):
    # print('recv:', repr(data))
    self.server_transport.write(data)

    def connection_lost(self, *args):
    self.server_transport.close()


class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    INIT, HOST, DATA = 0, 1, 2

    def connection_made(self, transport):
    print('from:', transport.get_extra_info('peername'))
    self.transport = transport
    self.state = self.INIT

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
    self.transport.close()

    def data_received(self, data):
    # print('send:', repr(data))

    if self.state == self.INIT:
        assert data[0] == 0x05
        self.transport.write(pack('!BB', 0x05, 0x00))  # no auth
        self.state = self.HOST

    elif self.state == self.HOST:
        ver, cmd, rsv, atype = data[:4]
        assert ver == 0x05 and cmd == 0x01

        if atype == 3:    # domain
            length = data[4]
            hostname, nxt = data[5:5+length],  5+length
        elif atype == 1:  # ipv4
            hostname, nxt = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, data[4:8]), 8
        elif atype == 4:  # ipv6
            hostname, nxt = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, data[4:20]), 20
        port = unpack('!H', data[nxt:nxt+2])[0]

        print('to:', hostname, port)
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.connect(hostname, port))
        self.state = self.DATA

    elif self.state == self.DATA:
        self.client_transport.write(data)

    async def connect(self, hostname, port):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    socks5_addr = aiosocks.Socks5Addr('127.0.0.1', 1080)
    dst = (hostname, port)
    transport, client = await aiosocks.create_connection(Client, proxy=socks5_addr, proxy_auth=None, dst=dst)
    client.server_transport = self.transport
    self.client_transport = transport
    hostip, port = transport.get_extra_info('sockname')
    host = unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(hostip))[0]
    self.transport.write(
        pack('!BBBBIH', 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, host, port))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    srv = loop.create_server(Server, 'localhost', 8000)
    loop.run_until_complete(srv)
    loop.run_forever()
```

what should i do to fix at least one of this problems?

if you know any other libraries, please say me.

thanks